# Powershell script running as GPO Shutdown script not getting the currently logged in User

Tags: powershell, gpo

Hello i am writing a ps script to save some data for specific Users and their PCs in our Domain.
On the destination Server i created shares for every user, that are named after the users, that will use this script.
`\\Servername\user`
When i run the script locally on my PC it runs fine, but when it runs through the GPO as SYSTEM,
both these ways to get the currently logged in user return null and so i cant build the path to copy the Files to the Dest Server
`$(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username`
`(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name="explorer.exe"').GetOwner().User`
So how can i get the currently logged in User in a powershell script executing as GPO Shutdown script?

Here is the transcript of explorer version:

```
nStart der Windows PowerShell-Aufzeichnung 
Startzeit: 20210630151918
Benutzername: BM\SYSTEM
RunAs-Benutzer: BM\SYSTEM
Konfigurationsname: 
Computer: JANOSCH (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Hostanwendung: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\bm.local\SysVol\bm.local\Policies\{1CE1F419-5504-4C4A-87CB-347362B0DC70}\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\LaptopSicherungTest.ps1
Prozess-ID: 11056
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.752
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.752
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Die Aufzeichnung wurde gestartet. Die Ausgabedatei ist "c:\temp\PowerShell_transcript.JANOSCH.Ujz6Mkz7.20210630151918.txt".
Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In \\bm.local\SysVol\bm.local\Policies\{1CE1F419-5504-4C4A-87CB-347362B0DC70}\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\LaptopSicherungTe
st.ps1:19 Zeichen:1
+ $user =(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name="explorer.ex ...
```

The username version doesnt give an error because the Variable is just NULL and i am not invoking a function on it.

Comment: Would a log off script make more sense? At least that will run in the users context

Comment: If you run it as a GPO startup script, the script probably runs beforre any user is logged on, meaning that you probably have to wait for a while for any user to logon. You might consider to create a GPO with a scheduled task instead.